# How to analyze Type object from TypeScript compiler API?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, typescript-compiler-api

*Note:* This question is about [the TypeScript compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Architectural-Overview), *not* about TypeScript as a language!

---

I have a value of type `ts.Type`. I want to know what type it represents: Is it a number? A function? An array?

I found that `type.flags` allows me to perform roughly the static equivalent of the `typeof` operator, allowing me to differentiate between primitive types such as `number`, `string`, and `boolean` (but not functions). Anything else -- arrays, functions, POJOs, etc. -- simply has the `TypeFlags.Object` flag.

How can I further examine these non-primitive types? How do I determine whether a type is an array, a function, an enum, a class instance...?

Comment: You can use `type.symbol.name` to get the name of the type.

Answer (score 0):

There is another field on types that have `Typeflags.Object`.
Its called `type.objectFlags` and you can use it to further distinguish the type